# Spring Integration - messages sporadically are not getting processed and are going to null channel

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am using SI's aggregator and using custom aggregator and release strategy. PFB the snippet

```
        return IntegrationFlows.from("uaDefaultChannel").wireTap(UA_WIRE_TAP_CHNL).transform(eventHandler, "parseEvent")
                .aggregate(a -> a.correlationStrategy(corStrgy, "getCorrelationKey").releaseStrategy(g -> {
                    System.out.println("time entered"+System.currentTimeMillis()); 
                    boolean eonExists = g.getMessages().stream()
                            .anyMatch(eon -> ((FlightModel) eon.getPayload()).getEstGmtOnDtm() != null);
                    if (eonExists) {
                        boolean einExists = g.getMessages().stream()
                                .anyMatch(ein -> ((FlightModel) ein.getPayload()).getEstGmtInDtm() != null);
                        if (einExists) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }).messageStore(this.messageStore)).handle(uaImpl, "process").get();
```

Its going to corelate startegy class but then its directly going to the null channel, I am using JdbcMessage store. Its not going into h Release Strategy class. PFB the log -

```
2020-01-28T13:18:55.472-0600 DEBUG Executing prepared SQL query
2020-01-28T13:18:55.472-0600 DEBUG Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT COMPLETE, LAST_RELEASED_SEQUENCE, CREATED_DATE, UPDATED_DATE from INT_MESSAGE_GROUP where GROUP_KEY = ? and REGION=?]
2020-01-28T13:18:55.472-0600 DEBUG Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2020-01-28T13:18:55.473-0600 DEBUG message sent to null channel: GenericMessage [payload=Flight [UA/1016/20200128/IAH0-CUN: status=null, EON=null(GMT: null), EIN=null(GMT: 2020-01-28 20:15:43), tail=null], headers={jms_redelivered=false, jms_destination=Queue[UAL.OPS.NOC.FLIGHTAWARE.FLIFO.1], id=03accd44-2e22-eb3d-cf0a-2c291f8562b6, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1580239135458, jms_messageId=ID:DNDCEM01.309B5DA0C7C1C27739:181824, timestamp=1580239135471}]
2020-01-28T13:18:55.473-0600 DEBUG postSend (sent=true) on channel 'uaEventFlow.channel#0', message: GenericMessage [payload=Flight [UA/1016/20200128/IAH0-CUN: status=null, EON=null(GMT: null), EIN=null(GMT: 2020-01-28 20:15:43), tail=null], headers={jms_redelivered=false, jms_destination=Queue[UAL.OPS.NOC.FLIGHTAWARE.FLIFO.1], id=03accd44-2e22-eb3d-cf0a-2c291f8562b6, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1580239135458, jms_messageId=ID:DNDCEM01.309B5DA0C7C1C27739:181824, timestamp=1580239135471}]
```

Some of the messages are getting processed but majority of the messages are going to the null channel.

Comment: Hi Gary - After further analysis it seems that the message with the same correlation key is causing the issue. If the Group is completed and then the message arrives with the same key then it is going to the null channel. I looked into the AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler. Can you suggest how we can handle this scenario with expireGroupsoncompletion or a better way

Answer (score 2):

I deleted my comment; you are correct; new messages for expired groups will be sent to the `nullChannel` if there is no discard channel.

Set `expireGroupsUponCompletion` to `true` to expire groups so that a new group is started with a new message with the same correlation id.